# in c or c++, how can you distinguish between 0 which is set on an address in memory and 0 which is set because that address is not initialized?

Tags: c++, memory

I have an if condition in my code, which I check the value which is set in a specific address in memory. If this value is 0, then I assume that this address is not set and will do some actions. But there can be the case where I do this check and value is 0 because I have set it to 0 somewhere else in the code. How can I distinguish between these two conditions?

Comment: Show the code instead of describing it.

Comment: You don't. There's no way to distinguish a 0 from a 0.

Comment: You could store the information that the address is not set in another variable (`1` -> set, `0` -> not set).

Answer (score 3):

You don't. There's no way to distinguish a 0 from a 0.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You'll have to define additional, static variable, say

```
int initialized = 0;
```

and set it to `1` when you assign your memory location any new value. Then you can test `if(initialized)...` to tell zero from zero.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot distinguish between different '0', 0 is 0.
It is also intrinsically difficult to represent more than 2 states with a binary variable. 
As far as I understand you have more than 2 states.
1. Variable =0 not initialized, do stuff.
2. Variable =1 initialized, do other stuff.
3. Variable =0 and initialized, do different stuff.
There is no way to understand the state without using additional information. 
So you could use another data structure to save more information.

Answer (score 0):

The two zeros are indistinguishable.

You *could* use a `std::pair<T, bool>` to encapsulate the initialisation status (in the bool) of a variable of type `T`.

(`std::pair<T, bool>` is used in the C++ standard library as the return value of an insertion into a `std::map`.)